# What dependencies does running "git svn" need to have installed in order to run correctly?

Tags: linux, git, git-svn

I've been struggling with getting a Subversion to Git migration to work on a corporate-IT managed Red Hat 6.4 Linux workstation.  Our IT organization provides several versions of most of the OTS packages they think we'll need by mounting them under an "/apps" directory on our local workstations.  *I do not have root or sudo on my box*, or this would probably be easier.  Following some blog posts (such as [this one](http://jmoses.co/2014/03/21/moving-from-svn-to-git.html)), and trying to set up my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH correclty, I've gotten to the point where I've done a successful `git svn init <my/svn/path>`, but running the `git svn fetch` yields errors such as:

```
Can't load '/apps/subversion_1.9.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld//auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so' for module SVN::_Core:
/apps/subversion_1.9.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld//auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so:
undefined symbol: svn_swig_pl_thunk_config_enumerator at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
```

at /apps/subversion_1.9.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld//SVN/Base.pm line 59
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /apps/subversion_1.9.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld//SVN/Core.pm line 5.

I've tracked down the library that contains this symbol (seems like this could be an issue with compilation paths) to be `libsvn_swig_perl-1.so`.  I set the LD_PRELOAD env variable in bash to the path to that library, but then running the `git svn fetch` gives me a new error:

```
/apps/git_2.9.3/bin/git: symbol lookup error: 
/apps/subversion_1.9.4/lib/libsvn_swig_perl-1.so: undefined symbol: PL_thr_key
```

I have not yet been able to successfully locate what package and library "PL_thr_key" comes from.  Any hints on where I can get a full list of dependencies (or at least where PL_thr_key is defined) to hopefully get my svn-to-git migration finished?

Answer (score 1):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of a repository. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like and also excluding any paths or branches or tags you don't to have migrated, though I'm always crying a little if someone discards code history which is precious.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` or the nirvdrum `svn2git` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- you can generate annotated tags instead of lightweight tags
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: The clincher for me was this line in the README: `sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion git qtchooser qt5-default libapr1 libapr1-dev libsvn-dev`, since I don't have root/sudo access on the company-provided box.  A coworker suggested I spin up a VM where I can have root privileges and do the migration there.  Going to give that a try.

Comment: Well, that is an example of how you do it with root access on a Debian based box. You can do it as well without root and package manager or in a VM. If not in a VM, you for example can install the missing dependencies from source, or you can use a `chroot` environment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that finally worked for me was to follow a co-workers suggestion, and create a VM where I had root/sudo access, copy the subversion repo in there, and do the conversion there--where I have control over installing matching versions of software.  Yes, it was higher effort than a simple `git svn clone`, but without the ability to easily troubleshoot the process, and trying to ferret out depenencies between possibly mismatched versions of svn and git, it wound up being the best solution in the end.  In case this winds up being helpful to anyone else.  On an AWS ubuntu 16.04 LTS Virtual Machine, I installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion git qtchooser qt5-qmake libapr1 libapr1-dev libsvn-dev
```

This gave me the following version combination for git and svn:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.9.3 (r1718519)
```

After this, the `git svn clone` went fairly smooth, the only hitch was remembering to use a `file:///path/to/svn/repo` format to point to the repo, as it was unhappy with an absolute path.

As a footnote, I did try the `svn-all-fast-export` option mentioned by Vampire's answer, but was ultimately unable to get that working (I dead ended at a core dump before going back to `git svn clone`).

Comment: If you want to give `svn2git` another chance, tell more about the error. Did you give it a local path to the SVN repo, not a remote URL?

Comment: @Vampire Yes, it was run with a local path to the repo (used a standard path, not file:/// URI notation).  At this point, that sprint is done, and I'm on to the next task. :)